# OpenSea mint inconsistently ether tokenID on smart contract ERC-721

Tags: ethereum, solidity, nft, opensea

How OpenSea check available tokenIDS for SmartContact?
Can i mint tokenID inconsistently?
Example ID:1 and next ID:600

I ask this question, because I do not understand how OpenSea finds out which tokens are and which are not. Not indefinitely they have an indexer going that from 0 to infinity.

I didn't see any methods in ERC721 to return list all mint tokens.
How is work?

Answer (score 0):

You can create ERC721 token contract on
https://wizard.openzeppelin.com/#erc721 and add an array called e.g. mintedIds[], then add to the mint function `mintedIds.push(tokenId);`

Also add view returns function that will this array.

After deploying this contract to the testnet you would be able to mint nft manualy and this array will store the IDs that were minted.

If you'll use counters while creating nft contract (optional on wizard) it will automaticaly increment the ID by 1 everytime you mint.

Comment: how does opensea understand that mint has occured? I can change function name from 'mint' to other, can create self link array account-nft, can mint  inconsistently  ids, but opensea whatever understand that has mint. Function from erc721 'tokenURI' requare only 1 token id and return url to one id but if i have inconsistently  ids you cant crunch the numbers.